# WebClient.UploadProgressChanged event handler to working for OneDrive file upload API?

Tags: c#, office365, webclient, onedrive, office365api

While uploading a file using onedrive API for simple item upload,the progresschanged event fires only after the whole file is uploaded and no progress is reported in between.The e.progresspercentage first gives 100 value and then gives some large negative value.Is this problem with the OneDrive API or webclient.I am using .net framework 3.5 with VS2008. I am using WebClient.UploadDataAsync function,and the HTTP method is "PUT".

Comment: I found the same issue with .NET Framework 3.5. However, with .NET 4.5, the progress is shown alright. The data streams seems to be send with 8Kbytes slices.

Comment: We can try looking at the UploadDataAsync implementation with .NET Reflector.

Comment: It worked when I used uploadfileAsync function.